# I need log4j 1.2 and 2.5 to coexist in the same webapp

Tags: java, crystal-reports, log4j, classloader, log4j2

I have a java webapp that uses Crystal's Business Objects runtime to run a report coded in that technology. The problem is that the monkeys at Crystal directly referenced a method in a log4j 1.2 class.  This method isn't part of the log4j 1.2 to 2.5 bridge api.  Nor should it be because Crystal shouldn't be calling it directly.

I have no choice but to use Crystal, our organization is locked in on it. I can only choose to either roll back the entire app to NOT use log4j2.5 like all of our other apps, OR I need to find a way they can coexist.  When i put both jars in the classpath, the app tends to get confused as to what to load and we get no logging out.  Remove that jar, and logging works great...but Crystal bombs.

I really don't want to roll everything back to 1.2.  Is there a way to make them coexist nicely?  Like make 1.2 higher on the classloader only when calling Crystal or something? Anyone know some trick that can help me here?

Comment: You can use different versions of a class in the same JVM, but then you need **multiple** class loaders. So, this is possibly, but on the very advanced end of things.

Comment: Maybe, just maybe...Get the entire project of Log4j version which you want and then modify the name such that the conflict does not happen with Crystal's Log4J  method. The trade off will be that as you will be locked to the specific version of the Log4J you are going to use, and you will have the overhead of managing the Log4J Jar file.

Comment: Another approach is to isolate the Crystal related code as a service running in another JVM (or at least in a different web conext).  Then your app, which has no direct knowledge of Crystal or it's dependencies, calls the service as needed.  Also, open a ticket with Crystal.

Answer (score 1):

**proxy-object** [proxy-object library](https://github.com/avinokurov/proxy-object/blob/master/README.md#proxy-object)

Put Crystal jar and all its dependencies in a folder (/path/to/crystalLib/)

**Code Examples**

Create any class from the Crystal library:

```
    File libDir = new File("/path/to/crystalLib/");

    ProxyCallerInterface caller = ObjectBuilder.builder()
            .setClassName("org.crystal.report")
            .setArtifact(DirArtifact.builder()
                    .withClazz(this.getClass())
                    .withVersionInfo(newVersionInfo(libDir))
                    .build())
            .build();
    String version = caller.call("crystalMethod").asString();
```

proxy-object library will handle separate class loader mess and you should be able to load any conflicting dependancies this way.